# UK Visa - Have you passed an approved English language test?

Tags: uk-visa, paperwork

I am applying for UK spouse visa. I need to provide a proof of English language knowledge, I have a test booked well before the time I need to upload the evidence(biometrics appointment), but after I submit the application online.

Should I answer yes or no to Have you passed an approved English language test?

Comment: Answer **No**. How can you answer ‘yes’ if you’ve not passed the test *before* the submission date? The question doesn’t say ‘… or do you have a test date booked’